# SQLite query for two tables

Tags: sqlite

I have following DB structure:

[image: Schema]

Query for DB creation: http://pastebin.com/camRJ27C

I want to create a query for the result like:
id(should be the same as catalog_id from Groups table) -- name -- COUNT(catalog_id) -- catalog_id

Tried to run query:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(catalog_id), catalog_id
from Catalogs LEFT JOIN Groups on Catalogs.id = Groups.Catalog_id
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC
```

but it returns everything except "id" with error in DB Browser for SQLite:

> ambiguous column name: id: SELECT id,name, COUNT(catalog_id), catalog_id from Catalogs LEFT JOIN Groups on Catalogs.id = Groups.Catalog_id GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC

Can you please give me some advice?

Comment: Please take care of your formatting; I have edited your question to be somewhat more readable, but the optimum might not yet been reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on table for which you need `id` you can modify it's name in this query:

`SELECT Catalogs.id as id, name, COUNT(catalog_id), catalog_id 
 FROM Catalogs LEFT JOIN Groups on Catalogs.id = Groups.Catalog_id
 GROUP BY name 
 ORDER BY name ASC;`